# Portable Firefox: Portableapps vs Direct update widely different sizes

Tags: firefox, portable-apps

I have Portable FF 43.0.1 in my Win 10. 
Portableapps offered me to update it (Main Menu - Apps - Check for updates) to FF 45.0.1, quoting a size of 95Mb, which, just in case, I verified it was the size of the download after launching the update). 
On the other hand, if I launch the update directly from FF (Help - About - Check for updates) it downloads about 50Mb.

**Why the difference?**

PS: After updating from within FF, the Portableapps updater still shows that I need the update (at the same 95Mb). This is not surprising, but it could perhaps be spared.

Comment: The difference is not limited to updates. It's simply the difference of their installers.

Comment: @TomYan - As I understand, a Portableapp is the same app, with a [launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_desktop_application_launchers) and some configuration files, which takes up little space. I would expect that, even if the app needs recompilation for a Portableapps version, the differences in size are minimal. What are the extra 45Mb needed for?

Comment: @TomYan - Now it is clear why the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From PortableApps<sup>[[1]](http://portableapps.com/support/firefox_portable#32and64)</sup>:

> Firefox Portable includes both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Firefox and will use the appropriate version on each PC.

This was introduced in version 43<sup>[[2]](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Edition%2042.0/)[[3]](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Edition%2043.0/)</sup>:

```
FirefoxPortable_42.0_English.paf.exe    2015-11-03  45.9 MB
FirefoxPortable_43.0_English.paf.exe    2015-12-17  97.2 MB
```

Comment: Right. And [this](http://portableapps.com/news/2015-12-16--firefox-portable-43.0-released) too

Comment: ... specifically where John Haller says "While this does double the install and download size, the resulting dual mode version of Firefox is about the same size as many of our other browsers."